# To Execute the same jar simultaneously from different computers

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a requirement like I have created an executable jar file . I need to run it from different systems parallel say 5 . Is it possible through java code to execute it so that all jar starts at the different systems simultaneously? Please help

Answer (score 1):

How about...

- add a start parameter `- startup 12:00`
- wait in main for that time
- start logic

All the computers would need same time - but thats not too hard